# syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE)

Tags: php

```
$tabla.='
<td>
    <select name="inspeccionasignar-reg" class="form-control">';
        $dataIns=self::datos_inspeccion_asignar_controlador("Select",0);
$tabla.=while($rowIns=$dataIns->fetch()){

echo '<option value="'.mainModel::encryption($rowIns['      AgenteCodigo']).'">
            Agente: ' .$rowIns['          Nombre'].'    
            Apellido:   ' .$rowIns['          Apellido'].'
            Matricula:  ' .$rowIns['Matricula'].
    '</option>';

            }
$tabla.='</select>      
</td>';
```

Estoy intentando mostrar en un select los valores de una base de datos en php,necesito hacerlo si o si de esta forma pero en la linea donde esta el while me sale este error y no puedo solucionarlo.Que podria ser?

Comment: Creo que el `echo` no debe ir dentro de una variable... al menos nunca vi eso.

Comment: antes del while tienes un `$tabla.=` debe ir donde esta el `echo` y al final del script entonces si va `echo $tabla;`

Comment: pero no tendria que ir el echo dento de una variable concatenada... a eso me refiero, en todo caso declaras la variable y despues haces el `echo` para que se ejecute lo que esta dentro

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**

**WHILE**

El significado de una sentencia `while` es simple. Le dice a PHP que ejecute las sentencias anidadas, tanto como la expresión `while` se evalúe como `TRUE`.

El valor de la expresión es verificado cada vez al inicio del bucle, por lo que incluso si este valor cambia durante la ejecución de las sentencias anidadas, la ejecución no se detendrá hasta el final de la iteración.

A veces, si la expresión `while` se evalúa como `FALSE` desde el principio, las sentencias anidadas no se ejecutarán ni siquiera una vez.

EJEMPLO

```
<?php

$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i++;
}

// RESULTADO - 12345678910

?>
```

---

Una manera simple de hacerlo es asi:

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tabla");

<select name="catt" id="inputState" class="form-control">
  <option selected>Seleccione un equipo</option>
    <?php
      while ($fila = $sql->fetch()) {
    ?>

  <option value="<?=$fila['id'];?>"><?=$fila['nombre'];?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

De esta manera tendras menos problemas a la hora de tenes un lista de los datos que sean necesarios.

Comment: Aunque estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo en que es mejor enviar el contenido directamente, es probable que quien pregunta necesite almacenarlo en una variable y tu respuesta sería más completa si también incluyes esa opción.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices y lo comparto, pero guardad un bucle dentro de una variable, es algo que no se si se puede hacer. Es por eso que di esta respuesta.

Comment: Vamos a supones que el ejemplo que di lo guardo en una variable: `$valor = while ($i <= 10) { echo $i++; };`, el resultado es el mismo: ` syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE)`. Entonces entro en mismo error. Si un bucle pude ser guardado dentro de una variable, no lo sabia y pido disculpas por eso!

Comment: Definitivamente no puedes guardar el while, sino que dentro del ciclo concatenas las opciones a la variable.